# wordpress not loading on localhost

Tags: localhost

I have a localhost website `bm.ourdomain.local` on our Mac machine (running AMPPS).

It has an entry in `/etc/hosts`:

```
<local IP> bm.ourdomain.local
```

It has an entry in `/Applications/AMPPS/Apache/conf/extra/vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin hello@ourdomain.local
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/AMPPS/www/bm.ourdomain.local"
    ServerName bm.ourdomain.local
    ServerAlias bm.ourdomain.local
    ErrorLog "/Applications/AMPPS/www/bm.ourdomain.local/error_log"
    CustomLog "/Applications/AMPPS/www/bm.ourdomain.local/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

When I load `bm.ourdomain.local` in Chrome, nothing happens, the loading icon just spins.

If I turn on debug, `debug.log` doesn't get created.

If I rename `plugins` to `plugins.temp`, nothing changes, same with `themes` to `themes.temp`.

There is Wordfence installed, and I have confirmed `.htaccess` and `.user.ini` contain the correct path to `wordfence-waf.php`.

There is no `error_log`.

If I clear the browser cache of files and cookies, nothing changes.

Other websites on the local server run fine, on vhosts.

Help appreciated.

Comment: If your working on WordPress local host try this one, DesktopServer. https://serverpress.com/

Comment: Are the file permissions set correctly, so that the webserver can read these files? What do you mean by "loading icon spins"?

Comment: Permissions are fine thanks @kero. When Chrome loads a page there is a loading icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting the AMPPS server resolved this issue.

Every day since the problem the website has loaded fine since, so it looks like the problem was isolated to one occurrence.